# How to properly serialize *-to-many relationships with DRF

Tags: python, django, rest, serialization, django-rest-framework

I've been trying to serialize/deserialize some data using the DRF but I'm not sure what's going wrong.

Here are my models:

```
from django.db import models

class FooA(models.Model):
    propA = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class FooB(models.Model):
    propB = models.CharField(max_lenght=30)
    propC = models.ForeignKey(FooC, related_name='fooBs')

class FooC(models.Model):
    propC = models.CharField(max_lenght=30)
    fooAs = models.ManyToMany(FooA, null=True, blank=True)
```

Here are my serializers:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from myModule import models

class FooASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.FooA
        fields = ('propA',)

class FooBSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.FooB
        fields = ('propB',)

class FooCSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    fooBs = FooBSerializer(many=True)
    fooAs = FooASerializer(many=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = models.FooC
        fields = ('fooAs', 'fooBs',)
```

Here is my "view":

```
from rest_framework import generics
from .serializers import FooCSerializer
from .models import FooC

class FooCList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    model = FooC
    serializer_class = FooCSerializer
```

And, finally, here is my routing:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include
from .views import FooCList

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^foocs/', FooCList.as_view())
)
```

So, what I was trying to do was to create some data through the admin interface, then go to the DRF api browser, copy one FooC object's JSON, slightly modify it and test if I would succeed on deserializing it to a FooC object.

Here is what I've done:

```
>>> from rest_framework.compat import BytesIO
>>> from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
>>> from myApp.serializers import FooCSerializer
>>>
>>> content = '<slightly modified JSON copied from the DRF api browser>'
>>> stream = BytesIO(content)
>>> data = JSONParser().parse(stream)
>>> serializer = FooCSerializer(data=data)
>>> serializer.is_valid()
True
>>> serializer.save()
ValueError: Cannot add "<FooA: fooA>": instance is on database "default", value is on database "None"
```

Notice that it does create a new FooC instance in my database, but it does not create neither of its "nested" classes (aka. classes FooC has a relationship with).

So here are a couple questions:

1) **Is this expected?** I was hoping it would create everything "on cascade".

2) **In case this happens by design, how am I supposed to act when building my client?** I mean, I was expecting to open a form where I could create instances of FooC and every related instance within the same form.

Thank you, guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answers:

1) Yes.

2) There are possible workarounds.

In order for you to understand why I said yes to the first question, I recommend you to read the explanations here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/django-rest-framework/vCl2I_EzJnE/qwRdIdxiUe4J written by creator of DRF, Tom Christie.

Now for the workarounds, you could either:

1) Use the pre_save method to create your nested objects in a for loop and then add their PKs to the FooC current instance

2) Create a view for your nested classes and then call the method from that view with the corresponding data from your request.

Hope this helps :)